# Ckedtior Events to dynamically change the label text

Tags: ckeditor

can i create an event on Ckedtor where as soon as i write some thing in textarea of editor the same should dynamically update on another label below it using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer 
 ck.on('change',function(){
            $('#lblemailmsg').text(CKEDITOR.instances['spnemailsignature'].getData());

Comment: but <br/> or other tags are appearing in the label